# How to add/embed custom font file to FontFactory.register in iText

Tags: java, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I need your assistant in adding a custom font to the Java Class for writing PDF. The selected font is arial.ttf and it is located in the below path:

> Web App -> public html -> resources -> arial.ttf

My previous code for testing was to read the font from the c: drive:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c://windows//fonts//arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Now I want to make the Web app as WAR file and to deploy it and I need to change the path from the c: drive to the path:

> Web App -> public html -> resources -> arial.ttf

I tried also to embed the file from its location

```
FontFactory.register("/resources/fonts/arial.ttf");
```

However it always produces the below error:

> java.io.IOException: /resources/fonts/arial.ttf not found as file or
> resource.

I tried different ways to refer to the file for example:

> /public_html/resources/fonts/arial.ttf
>
> ../resources/fonts/arial.ttf
>
> /fonts/arial.ttf
>
> /arial.ttf

But I wasn't successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FontFactory.register(System.getProperty("file.separator")+"resources"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"fonts"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"arial.‌​ttf", "my_bold_font");
 Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_bold_font");
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up including two copies of the same fonts files in the project, one as Embedded Resources, and another one as Content. You can read from the Content one with regular relative path.

Nasty workaround but it worked.